# Typescript: filter BehaviourSubjet asObservable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm pretty new to angular and I'm wondering what I'm missing in this situation:

In a service I create a `BehaviorSubject` to store Websocket events:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalEvent {
  private _events: BehaviorSubject<IWSEvent[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  private socket;
  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(AppConfig.websocketClient);
    this.socket.on('event', (data: IWSEvent) => {
      const collection = this._events.value;
      collection.push(data.msg.object);
      this._events.next(collection);
    });
  }

  list() {
    return this._events.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Then in another service I'm subscribing to the `Observable` I'm returning:

```
@Injectable()
export class InstanceStore {
  constructor(private instanceService: InstanceService, private globalEvent: GlobalEvent) {
    this.globalEvent.list()
      .filter((e) => {
        return e.model === 'Instance';
      })
      .subscribe(
        (data: IWSEvent[]) => {
          const event = data[data.length - 1];
          console.log(event, data);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the error: `Property 'model' does not exist on type 'IWSEvent[]'.` in the filter function while I was expecting to find a single `IWSEvent` as parameter of the filter function, not the array.

What I'm not understanding?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a type mismatch. You have a `BehaviorSubject<IWSEvent[]>` which will send an instance of `IWSEvent[]` for each `next()` call but your filter seems to be written for a single instance of `IWSEvent`.

From what it looks like you don't really want to store your events in an array but just have a stream of `BehaviorSubject<IWSEvent>` then your filter will work as intended and you don't need to grab the last item of the array in your subscribe method.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got what I was missing. Calling `asObservable` I was expecting to receive only the last `IWSEvent[]` array, while I'm receiving an array of `IWSEvent[]` arrays, one for each time I called next. Is that right?